Neo4J NeoSemantics: PlugIn installation on Neo4J v.1.5.9/5.12
To upload an existing ontology from Protege to Neo4J, I want to set up NeoSemantics.
Following the
NeoSemantics Installation Docu, but it doesn't work for me.
I've downloaded the .jar files (5.11.0.jar & 5.14.0.jar) from GitHub and put it into the /plugins folder.
I've tried the following with both of the files in the folder separately, and restarted the DB and Neo4J between the switches:
Where I fail is point 2 of the docu - editing the line dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=n10s.endpoint=/rdf
in the file <NEO_HOME>/conf/neo4j.conf , which is read-only.
I've tried saving it and replacing the old file in the destination, but it reverts the changes, or recreates the file (with the same old date-modified from '23 in my case).
Changing the line from inside Neo4J seems to get saved, but doesn't seem to have an impact on the outcode concerning the n10s plugin.
Therefore I'm stuck with the Detecting n10s plugin... notification in the NeoSemantics window.
Is the documentation outdated, or am I missing something?

I'm able to update the .conf file, but still can't open Neosemantics, I tried this: https://community.neo4j.com/t/neosemantics-plugin-is-not-detected/21388/9
The solution given there didn't work for me, but maybe you'll have more luck
Seems like it's a persistent error with no clear solution that works for everyone

After some research and asking around, my baseline is that neosemantics is no longer up to date and therefore currently useless.
